# Complete MoveIt! Pick and Place example? (ideally with Gazebo integration)

Tags: ros, moveit, pick-and-place

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is [this nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jk_s98U5ob8) of a (real) PR2 performing Pick&Place using ORK and MoveIt!. Is the demonstrated (launch file) setup available somewhere? I´d like to take a look at it to see the component interaction between perception, planning and execution. If not, are there any other examples available that demonstrate MoveIt! based pick and place, ideally with the option of running them in Gazebo simulation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188144/complete-moveit!-pick-and-place-example?-(ideally-with-gazebo-integration)/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-07-29**:
I'm working on it for a TB2, but I have still a lot to do. So yeah, any working demo would be very appreciated.

**Comment by [danielsnider](https://answers.ros.org/users/29280/danielsnider/) on 2017-02-06**:
I'm looking for an example too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the example in the book "Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming", on page 355. Look at the section called "Grasping using MoveIt!".

http://pdf.th7.cn/down/files/1603/Mastering%20ROS%20for%20Robotics%20Programming.pdf

---

Originally posted by [danielsnider](https://answers.ros.org/users/29280/danielsnider/) with karma: 203 on 2017-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sai kiran](https://answers.ros.org/users/31447/sai-kiran/) on 2017-08-27**:
Hi,

I done total according to that book.

In Moveit, Pick and place working fine 100%.

But in Gazebo, not working. Can you provide me the solution, for working in Gazebo.

**Comment by [macrot51](https://answers.ros.org/users/40414/macrot51/) on 2019-04-03**:
Hallo guys, could anyone find a good example?

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2019-04-03**:
The picking part is quite complex in Gazebo. The physics engine simulation is not precise enough to simulate a real pick most of the times. What you could do is move the gripper to the target position, and additionally create a fixed link between the gripper and the object at run time. Then when you continue moving the gripper the object will follow. There is a gazebo plugin for that https://github.com/pal-robotics/gazebo_ros_link_attacher